# Questions about $g(x)= \inf_{h \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have several question about the following functions
\begin{align}
g_1(x)= \inf_{h \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
g_2(x)= \inf_{h \in \mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \right|
\end{align}

Note that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then
\begin{align}
g_1(x) \le f^\prime(x). 
\end{align}

1. Do $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$  have names?
2. Do $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ have any applications?
3. What is required for $g_1(x)=f^\prime(x)$  for some given $x$?
4. Are there better bounds on $g_1(x)$ than  $g_1(x) \le f^\prime(x)$?

Comment: You don't want absolute values around the ratio? (also, this seems related to Lipschitz continuity)

Comment: @ClementC.  Most likely not. But if you have an answer about the function with an absolute value I would be interested in that too.

Comment: I haven't seen this before, but one observation, if $f''(x) \ge 0$ when $x>a$, and $f''(x) \le 0$ when $x<a$ then $g(a) = f'(a)$

Comment: @ClementC. Actually looking at it again, I do need absolute value. I have made the appropriate modifications.

Comment: @DougM Thank you.  Very nice.

Comment: @Lisa Are you sure you need to take the absolute value? The inequality you gave holds even without taking the absolute value, and there seem to be nicer properties without it.

Comment: @SamForster I modified my question to include both functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about your first two questions, but when it comes to question three, you have the following condition:

Given some fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that:

- $g_1(x_0) = f'(x_0) \iff \inf_{h \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} = f'(x_0)$
- $g_1(x_0) = f'(x_0) \iff \forall h \in \mathbb{R}, \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} \geq f'(x_0)$
- $g_1(x_0) = f'(x_0) \iff \forall h \in \mathbb{R}, f(x_0+h) \geq f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h$
- $g_1(x_0) = f'(x_0) \iff \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) \geq f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(h-x)$

You can best see this with a picture, but $f$ being differentiable at $x_0$ is equivalent to there being a best fit linear equation for $f$ around $x_0$. Incidentally this *best fit* linear equation is always

$L_{f,x_0} \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $L_{f,x_0}(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (h-x)$

So in other words the equality $g_1(x_0) = f'(x_0)$ holds if and only if the best fit linear equation $L_{f,x_0}$ forms a lower bound for $f$ (i.e. $f \geq L_{f,x_0}$).

---

Another way of thinking about this would be graphically. If you were to plot the graphs of $y = f(x)$ and $y = L_{f,x_0}(x)$, then equality will hold if and only if the graph of $f$ remains above (or touching) $L_{f,x_0}$ at all times. See the example below:

[image]

As you should be able to see in the above example - the equality $g_1(x) = f'(x)$ will hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, because $f$ will always be above the best linear fit, no matter which point you chose to take it.

---

As for your forth question - for general differentiable functions, there will never be a better bound than $g_1(x) \leq f'(x)$. Taking the function $f_c(x) = cx$ gives a simple example where $g(x) = f_c'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore $g_1$ can not be lower than $f'$ for general differentiable functions.

---

EDIT: I should also emphasize that $L_{f,x_0}$ being a lower bound for $f$ is the **ONLY** requirement for $g(x_0) = f'(x_0)$. Take this very crude Microsoft Paint drawing as an example of a crazy function that still obeys the equality:

[image]

---

FURTHER EDIT: Also whilst I don't think there are any names for the specific functions you gave, they are similar to "limit superior" and "limit inferior" functions. They have a practical application in that they always exist (even if a function is nowhere differentiable), and if:

$\inf_{h \in (x_0-r, x_0+r)} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \sim \sup_{h \in (x_0-r, x_0+r)} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$ as $r \to 0$

then this proves that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, with $f'(x_0) = \lim_{r \to 0} \inf_{h \in (x_0-r, x_0+r)} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$.

Comment: Also I answered this for your question before you changed it to include absolute value signs. If you include absolute value signs then the inequality you gave doesn't even hold. Take the function $f(x) = -x$ as an example.

Comment: @Thank you for your answer. I changed my question to take care of both cases.

Comment: I made a couple of edits that were too big to fit into the comments. I don't think that your function $g_2$ has any practical applications other than being $g_2 = |g_1|$ (though I could be wrong).